# Extract data structure / format from Protobuf

Tags: json, parsing, csv, protocol-buffers

I am seeking for quick and easy answer about Protobufs. I understand it's some sort of encoding that shrinks huge data knowing its format, but what I care about is to understand this: how can I get an original data format? Literally, without knowing all the details of how protobufs work, is there an original data structure in JSON or CSV or XML like a header info that is provided to protobuf to encode data and decode it back, and where that information is? It seems like .proto file is something different.

I am trying a bunch of parsers that fail as I ran them: parsepbf.py. But maybe, because I don't let it know what's the underlying data format is, the header, namely. And where to look for that header, in what file?

Comment: Maybe you should read [the basics](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/)?

Comment: Exactly. I looked at that. Too much info, no simple answer to the question where is data structure encoded.

Comment: What is 'message', for example, and how it relates to definition of the data structure? If message defines a data class or something, why it's a message. Very confusing. Does Protobuf works with structural or unstructured data? You need to know structure in advance, or it's like JSON? I need a simple answer, please!

Comment: I've never used exactly Protobuf, but I've used other, similar tools, and yes, you need to know the structure in advance. Protobuf data is structured, but it isn't self-describing, like e.g. XML.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you've misunderstood Protobufs. It is not a compression format. Protobuf is an *alternative to* JSON, XML, etc.; it is its own stand-alone format and does not contain any of the others.

The purpose of the `.proto` file is to define the structure of messages you wish to encode in Protobuf format. They are called "messages" because usually Protobuf is used to encode messages sent between servers, though sometimes it is also used to encode records stored to disk or in databases. Protocol Buffers generally isn't useful without a `.proto` file to define the format(s) you wish to work with.